# Better way to read data from stream?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, stream

Currently I try to implement a tcp based communication.
On this way, I've some exception while reading from a network stream.
For example, to block the reading function until data are received.
Is there a better way to reading data from a network stream?

At the moment my "protocol" works like the following:

1. send the length from a byte converted packet class
2. send the byte converted packet class (id, type, credentials, content information, content)
3. reading length from packet class
4. reading packet class
5. reading packet type from packet class
6. parsing packet class by packet type (factory)

So this is my simple implementation from a tcp communication, is there a better way?

Here's some code:

```
private void HandleThread()
{
    using (var stream = _client.GetStream())
    {
        while (_client.Available > 0)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[4];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(buffer, 0);

            buffer = new byte[length];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            var type = (PacketType)buffer[0];

            var parser = PacketFactory.Get(type);
            parser.Parse(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you perhaps share error that you are getting..? that might better help us understand what's going on in regards to recommending a better way if one is truly warranted..

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving code instead of problems with code. It would be more on topic on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/